# Complete example to implement Remote Cache Server/Client using JCS

Tags: caching, jcs

We have a requirement to maintain cache in an application which is deployed in JBoss/Wildfly. Other applications deployed in JBoss should be able to access the same cache to put or get operations.
Example: Application A: expected to act as Remote Cache Server
Application B, C and D, etc: expected to put and get values into the Cache maintained present in application A.

I have tried with configurations (attached) to perform this, but could not see the data put by one application in another application.

Kindly provide a sample configuration for both server and clients like cache.ccf, remote_cache.ccf, web.xml, etc. and Java code example to access the Remote Cache Server and put/get the cache elements.

It would be helpful if you could provide an end to end configuration with a working example Java code to access the same cache across different applications deployed in JBoss.
**cache.ccf (server)**

```
# Registry used to register and provide the
# IRemoteCacheService service.
registry.host=localhost
registry.port=1102
# call back port to local caches.
jcs.remotecache.serverattributes.servicePort=1102
# rmi socket factory timeout
jcs.remotecache.serverattributes.rmiSocketFactoryTimeoutMillis=5000
# cluster setting
jcs.remotecache.serverattributes.LocalClusterConsistency=true
jcs.remotecache.serverattributes.AllowClusterGet=true

# sets the default aux value for any non configured caches
jcs.default=DC
jcs.default.cacheattributes=org.apache.commons.jcs3.engine.CompositeCacheAttributes
jcs.default.cacheattributes.MaxObjects=1000
```

**cache.ccf (client)**

```
# Remote RMI Cache set up to failover
jcs.auxiliary.RFailover=org.apache.commons.jcs3.auxiliary.remote.RemoteCacheFactory
jcs.auxiliary.RFailover.attributes=org.apache.commons.jcs3.auxiliary.remote.RemoteCacheAttributes
jcs.auxiliary.RFailover.attributes.FailoverServers=localhost:1102
jcs.auxiliary.RFailover.attributes.RemoveUponRemotePut=true
jcs.auxiliary.RFailover.attributes.GetOnly=false
```

**web.xml**

```
<!--to initialize Remote Cache Servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JCSRemoteCacheStartupServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.commons.jcs3.auxiliary.remote.server.RemoteCacheStartupServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JCSRemoteCacheStartupServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jcs</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```